# Add arguments to the end of a url in Retrofit

Tags: java, rest, retrofit

So, I'm trying to make a REST request that looks like this: `https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/?client_id=[client_id]&api_key=[api_key]`

Where `https://api.digitalocean.com` is the endpoint, and `@GET("/droplets/")` would be the annotation. I would like the end bit to be added automatically, since it would be identical for any API requests I make, and it would be a hassle to add it to each request. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a `RequestInterceptor` instance to the `RestAdapter.Builder` which adds the query parameters.

Retrofit will invoke the request interceptor for every API call which allows you to append query parameters or replace path elements.

In this callback you will be able to append the `clientId` and `apiKey` query parameters for every request.

Comment: This is no longer working in Retrofit 2 :'( Is there a way to get it back? I have to add api key as parameter to each call for themoviedb.org…

Comment: **Edit** : I added a new answer for Retrofit 2 as I found the solution

Answer (score 7):

Here's my interceptor for Retrofit 2:

```
    private static class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private String mApiKey;

    public AuthInterceptor(String apiKey) {
        mApiKey = apiKey;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        HttpUrl url = chain.request().httpUrl()
                .newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("api_key", mApiKey)
                .build();
        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: `url()` instead of  `httpUrl()` in **okhttp3**